# PHP Code problem... data in array but missing something when displaying records in HTML?

Tags: php, html

This is a fairly straight forward DB request, the array 'data' display's correctly when using the pre_r() function but I'm running into an issue with the HTML table side of this, I can't get it to display any records. I'm missing something obvious here that is eluding me, any help?

```
<?php
$mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'DB') or             die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$data = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM line_job WHERE JOB_NO=36934 AND LINE_NO=2") or die($mysqli->error);

pre_r($data ->fetch_assoc());   //recordset array

function pre_r( $array ) {
    echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>[![enter image description here][1]][1]Detail</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Job Type</th>
                <th>Resp. Party</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <?php 
            while ($data = $data->fetch_assoc()): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['STATUS'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['JOB_TYPE'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['RESP_PRTY'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$data = $data->fetch_assoc()` That's a reassignment, so after the first row, you've lost your DB result. Use a different variable name.

Comment: `pre_r($data ->fetch_assoc())` already fetches a row, and probably thereby empties your result set. Unless you rewind the result set, there's nothing more to fetch in it.

Comment: Both of you were correct... many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$mysqli ->query()` returns a `mysqli_result` object. This object has a pointer pointing to the first record. Everytime you call `fetch_assoc()` on it, it returns a single record and increments the pointer by one to point to the next row OR returns NULL if there are not more rows.

Obviously, your Mysql query returns one row. By the time you call `$data->fetch_assoc()` the second time, there are no more rows left to fetch in the $data.

Comment: If the following creates a loop of the array of the $data object
`while ($data = $data->fetch_assoc()): ?>`
why am I only limited to calling the array once? The pre_r()  function is essentially doing the same is it not?
Just trying to understand why when I call the pre_r() function it appears that the while() function no longer works... Thanks

Comment: Read my answer to see why it doesnt work the second time. Then you can ask questions directly related to the answer :)